# Rails, Paperclip move file path after saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a blog on which you can post files in your articles. Now I've added an image gallery for each user. Is there any simple way to store the uploaded files from the new blog posts directly into this image gallery? Problem is that I have 3 Paperclip Models. One for the blog attachment, one for pictures and one for albums. I really don't know how to do that.

P.S. I was following the "Treebook" tutorial on teamtreehouse.com if this can help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think storing as a another attachment is a good approach.
 Rather you could copy the URL from the "blog post attachment" to the gallery
Assuming you have Post which has attachments and every time an image gets attached to a post you want to create a gallery. 
I don't know if this is what you want but I hope you get some idea

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image
    after_create: copy_image_to_gallery

def copy_image_to_gallery
  gallery = Gallery.new
  gallery.image_url = self.image.url
  gallery.save
end

end
```